# Facebook App Notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I would like to send notifications on their Facebook global icon when they get a comment in my app. And I found that Facebook offers us an API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

And I know that 
I should put the code below in my rails app.

```
POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …
```

I, however, can't understand where to put this code. And I have no idea how to realize this only when my app users get a comment. Could you help me?

Comment: are you trying to post to facebook's wall ? Or want to comment on some post ?

Comment: I would like to send notification to facebook global icon when they get some comment on my app.

Comment: What do you mean by comment- is it a facebook comment ? Do you have any callback after this comment is successful? If yes, simply make a POST request to the above API and create the notification.

Comment: It is a comment in my app, not in facebook. I would like to realize this.https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/notifications

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)

To use Graph Api with Ruby you can use [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)

Koala is a Facebook library for Ruby, supporting the Graph API (including the batch requests and photo uploads), the REST API, realtime updates, test users, and OAuth validation.

OR

[fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph)

Both are fairly simple to use, once you have `oauth_access_token` which you can get by an OAuth strategy for authenticating users against your *Facebook App*. You may want to have a look at [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook).

Informative blogs are out there, should be good to get you started.

http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/02/09/facebook-connect-with-rails-omniauth-devise/
https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw